# Get Latitude and longutude using google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I want to get the **latitude and longitude of the marker** using the **google map drag event**.(not marker drag event. I need to set the marker fixed).

This is my code

```
function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
                var mapOptions = {
                  center: myLatlng,
                  zoom: 8
                };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"),
                mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: ''
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
                // 0.1 seconds after the center of the map has changed,
                // set back the marker position.
                //alert(center)
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                  var center = map.getCenter();
                  marker.setPosition(center);
                }, 100);
            });

        }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JIJOMON K.A, try with below solution,

```
  function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
            var mapOptions = {
              center: myLatlng,
              zoom: 8
            };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: ''
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              var center = map.getCenter();
               console.log(marker.getPosition().lat());
               console.log(marker.getPosition().lng());
            }, 100);
        });
    }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```